# Using integer arithmetic, how do I determine which product pair is larger without calculating the product?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I to determine, given pairs $\{m_1, M_1\}$ and $\{m_2, M_2\}$, where $m_n \le 0$, $M_n \gt 0$ and $\{m_n, M_n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, which pair $\{m_1, M_2\}$ or $\{m_2, M_1\}$ will have the smallest and largest product, *WITHOUT* actually comparing the products, using only integer arithmetic?

Given that I want to determine:

$$ m_1 M_2 \lt m_2 M_1$$

using integer arithmetic, with integer results, I get:

$$ \Big\lceil {m_1 \over M_1} \Big\rceil \le \Big\lceil {m_2 \over M_2 } \Big\rceil$$

based on the results that ${-3 \over 2} = -1$

How do I use integer $\bmod$, in conjunction to the integer division, to determine which product will be bigger?

Please be gentle, I'm a programmer, not a math major. :)

Comment: This near duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806546/how-to-determine-which-pair-will-have-the-smallest-and-largest-product-without-a gives the impression that you have an *actual* problem you want to solve, but instead of asking about it, you're going to ask seven similar variants, hoping someone will guess what you really want.  What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?  (Also, again, having handled the three cases $m_1=0$, $m_2=0$, and $m_1 = m_2 = 0$ with an if-else ladder, everything might as well be positive.)

Comment: @EricTowers I'm trying to detect an overflow before it happens.  The only piece of the puzzle I'm missing is this situation that I'm posing in this question.  Actual Q would be I have 2 values $x$ and $y$ who's possible values are $x_{min} \le x \le x_{max}$ and $y_{min} \le y \le y_{max}$.  What are the possible resulting min and max values?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c for an overview, and http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1959565&seqNum=13 for excruciating detail on how to solve the problem you actually want to solve.

Comment: @EricTowers, thanks. I'll see if it has what I'm looking for.